# (DJANGO) How to save session for user shopping cart in to restore session in next login?

Tags: python, django, session, cart

guys, I create a shopping cart in Django with using session, but after logout, it removes my cart, and also I cannot see my cart on another computer . so please help me

Comment: Please provide some of your code (read the rules to post a question too) and if you are getting error messages, post them too. These things are useful for people trying to help you. Also, edit your phrasing. It may suggest that you want people to do your work for you instead of helping you to solve a problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot and should not attach your cart to a session for the following reasons.

1. sessions expire, so whats happens to you cart? (*gone with the wind...*)
2. Django creates new sessions per site visitor. This implies that two different devices can **never** have the same session

You should consider attaching carts to users instead.